# $X \subseteq \mathcal{P}(B)$ contains filters on $\mathcal{B}$, are $\bigcap_{F\in X}F$ and $\bigcup_{F\in X}F$ filters too?

Tags: boolean-algebra, filters

> Consider a Boolean algebra $\mathcal{B}:=(B,\leq,\lor,\land,^c,0,1)$ and $\phi \neq X \subseteq \mathcal{P}(B)$ whose elements are filters on $\mathcal{B}$. Show that:
>
> 1. $\bigcap_{F\in X}F$ is also a filter on $\mathcal{B}$. However, $\bigcup_{F\in X}F$ may not be a filter.
> 2. If $X$ is *totally ordered* by the inclusion relation $\subseteq$, then $\bigcup_{F\in X}F$ is a filter on $\mathcal{B}$.

I'm working with the definition: $F \subseteq B$ is a filter if -

- $F \neq \phi$
- If $x,y \in F$ then $x\land y\in F$
- If $x\in F$ and $x\leq y$ then $y\in F$

To start with, I need to show that $\bigcap_{F\in X}F \neq \phi$ - which I'm unable to do. **Can we find an element common to all filters** on $\mathcal{B}$, which may help us conclude that the intersection is not empty? I'm thinking in this direction because $X$ *might as well be the set of all filters* on $\mathcal{B}$.

Next, I want to show: if $x,y \in \bigcap_{F\in X}F$ then $x\land y\in \bigcap_{F\in X}F$. This seems easy, since $x,y \in \bigcap_{F\in X}F$ means that $x$ and $y$ are contained in every filter in $X\subseteq\mathcal{P}(B)$, and so is $x\land y$ (property of filters). Similarly for the last property, i.e. if $x \in \bigcap_{F\in X}F$ then $x$ is in every filter in $X$, and we know that filters are upwards closed - so if $x\leq y$ then $y$ is in every filter in $X$ (and hence in $\bigcap_{F\in X}F$)

Next, I want to show that $\bigcup_{F\in X}F$ (non-empty, of course) may not always be a filter - which calls for a counterexample? I'm unable to think of one. **So, when will $\bigcup_{F\in X}F$ not be a filter?** From the 2nd part, it seems that this may have something to do with *ordering*?

For the last part, since X is totally ordered, we could probably start off with $X= \{X_1,X_2,...\}$ (X may not be finite, who knows?), and w.l.o.g assume that $X_1 \subseteq X_2 \subseteq ...\subseteq X_i\subseteq X_{i+1}...$ (that's the total ordering defined by inclusion, yes?). How do I take it from here?

**TL;DR** I have shared my thoughts and work for every part of the question, and it would be a great help if I could get hints or insights that could help me complete my solution (happy to see other solutions also, though)! Thanks!

Comment: $B = 1_{\mathcal P(B)}$ is an element of every filter of $\mathcal P(B)$.

Comment: I'm not sure what the notation means?

Comment: $B$ is the top element of $\mathcal P(B)$, so it belongs to every filter of $\mathcal P(B)$.

Comment: Makes sense, since filters are upwards closed. Thanks!

Comment: If $B=\{a,b\}$ and $X=\{ \{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}, \{\{b\},\{a,b\}\} \}$, then $$\bigcup X = \{ \{a\}, \{b\}, \{a,b\} \},$$ which is not a filter.

Comment: @amrsa $\mathcal{P}(B) = \{\phi, \{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\} \}$ right? and $X \subseteq \mathcal{P}(B)$, as mentioned in the question. In the example you have taken, it seems like $X \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(B))$ - what do I have wrong? Should the question be rephrased to say that $X \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(B))$ instead?

Comment: You're right that $X \subseteq \mathcal P(\mathcal P(B))$, contrary to your hypothesis, which I overlooked. Now, $X$ is supposed to be a set of filters, and if $X \subset \mathcal P(B)$, that doesn't work: $x \in \mathcal P(B)$ for $x \subseteq B$; $F \subset \mathcal P(B)$ for $F$ a filter of $\mathcal P(B)$; and if $X$ is a set of filters, then...

Comment: @amrsa I think we got a little confused. $X \in \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(B))$ instead, and $X \subseteq \mathcal{P}(B)$ does seem right after all. Elements in $\mathcal{P}(B)$ are subsets of $B$ (some of which are filters), and $X$ is a subset of $\mathcal{P}(B)$, i.e. a set containing only those subsets of $B$ which are filters! Does this sound okay?

Comment: You are right. I overlooked your question and took $\mathcal P(B)$ to be the original Boolean algebra. So in the example I gave in a comment above, it should be $B = \mathcal P(\{a,b\})$. Anyway, I think you understood why the union of filters may not be a filter, right? Actually Brian's answer picks on my example.

Comment: Yes, understood it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the second question you cannot assume that $\langle X,\subseteq\rangle$ is even countable, let alone that it can be ordered like the positive integers: it might be ordered like $\Bbb R$, for instance. All that you can assume is that if $F_1,F_2\in X$, then either $F_1\subseteq F_2$, or $F_2\subseteq F_1$.

Let $G=\bigcup_{F\in X}F$. It’s clear that $G\ne\varnothing$. Suppose that $x,y\in G$; then there are $F_x,F_y\in X$ such that $x\in F_x$ and $y\in F_y$. Without loss of generality we may assume that $F_x\subseteq F_y$. Can you finish it from there and go on to show that $G$ is upward closed?

This proof should suggest how to find a counterexample when $X$ is not linearly ordered by inclusion: when you’ve finished it, you’ll see that we used the linear order only to show that $G$ was closed under $\land$. For a counterexample, then, we probably want an $X$ that contains filters $F_x$ and $F_y$ containing elements $x$ and $y$, respectively, but no filter containing both $x$ and $y$. The simplest way to do that is to let $X=\{F_x,F_y\}$, where $x,y\in B$, $x\in F_x\setminus F_y$, and $y\in F_y\setminus F_x$, and if we can ensure that $x\land y=0$, we’ll make certain that $F_x\cup F_y$ is not a filter.

Clearly we need $B$ to have at least two elements, and they have to be incomparable. (Otherwise, the larger one will be in the filter containing the smaller one.) If we set $x\lor y=1$, $x\land y=0$, $x^c=y$, and $y^c=x$, we have simple Boolean algebra whose partial order has this Hasse diagram:

```
                     1
                    / \
                   x   y
                    \ /
                     0
```

(It’s really just the power set algebra on a $2$-point set, as in **amrsa**’s comment.) And we can take $F_x=\{x,1\}$ and $F_y=\{y,1\}$ to get the desired counterexample: $F_x\cup F_y=\{x,y,1\}$, which is clearly not a filter, precisely because it doesn’t contain $x\land y$.

Comment: Just to complete the proof: (1) $x\in F_x, y\in F_y$ and $F_x\subseteq F_y$ means $x\in F_y$ so that $x\land y \in F_y \implies x\land y\in G$ (2) If $x \in G$ and $x\leq y$, consider the filter $F_x$ such that $x \in F_x$. Since $F_x$ is upwards closed, $y\in F_x$ hence $y\in G$. Sounds good?

Comment: @strawberry-sunshine: Looks good to me!